# If $(X_{t})_{1}^{\infty}$ is a stationary process, would the sigma-rings generated by $X_{t}$ the same for all $t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

This question is about a stationary process and the sigma-rings generated by its components.

Specifically, if $(X_{t})_{1}^{\infty}$ is a stationary process and $\mathscr{F}_{i}$ and $\mathscr{F}_{j}$ are the sigma-rings generated by $X_{i}$ and $X_{j}$ for $1 \leq i \neq j,$ then would we have
$$\mathscr{F}_{i} = \mathscr{F}_{j}$$
for all $i \neq j$?
Though intuitively this seems wrong, but I cannot see a reason.

Need your help, thanks!

Comment: Come, see, conquer... and acknowledge answers?

Comment: @Did: Right, thank you so much for your answer and sorry for the delay. Incidentally, you are humorous as shown in the comment :) HAHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No--that the process is stationary ensures that the *distribution* of $X_i$ does not depend on $i$, this has nothing to do with the identity $\sigma(X_i)=\sigma(X_j)$ for $i\ne j$, and in general these identities do not hold for stationary processes.

Example: if $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli, then $(X_i)$ is stationary but each $\sigma(X_i)$ is generated by $[X_i=1]$ and $[X_i=1]\notin\sigma(X_j)$ for every $i\ne j$.